# Check user id Already exist in database Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to Check if User id is already exist in database print false

```
$token  = "token";
 $data = json_decode(get_html("https://graph.facebook.com/$user->id&access_token=$token"))->data;

  $id = echo "".$user->id;
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM token_all WHERE id = $id"); 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
 $checkid = row[id];
  }
  if ($id == $checkid){
echo "true";
 }else{
echo "false";
 }
```

Comment: I don't think this code runs. Please provide a working version of the code.

Comment: I Also Try this but its not working

Comment: i want to get Facebook graph user id and check is already exist or not

Comment: @Anil, check my answer if that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a count and test if you get any results.
If you get results you already have the id in the database,
if you don't get any results the id is not there.

Also I removed `$id = echo "" . $user->id;` since we can use `$user->id` directly in the query.

One more thing, you should steer away from the `mysql_*` api since [it has been deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and move towards [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) or better `PDO`.

```
$token  = "token";
$data = json_decode(get_html("https://graph.facebook.com/$user->id&access_token=$token"))->data;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM token_all WHERE id = " . $user->id); 
$count = mysql_num_rows($result); // edited here

if ($count > 0){
    echo "ID already exists";
}else{
    echo "ID doesn't exist";
}
```

Comment: I edited a line, had a mistake in it, take a look again

Comment: Showing only true value

Comment: which one is the `true`, it exists or not? verify the query on your database and see how many users you have with that id.

Comment: Evey user have his own user Use deterrent ids

Comment: Evey User have his own id i am using his facebook user id Ex.,1100000454845

Answer (score 0):

your code has bugs, try this:

```
    $token  = "token";
 $data = json_decode(get_html("https://graph.facebook.com/$user->id&access_token=$token"))->data;

  $id = $user->id;
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM token_all WHERE id = $id"); 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
 $checkid = $row['id'];
  }
  if ($id == $checkid){
echo "true";
 }else{
echo "false";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

why the double check? if your sql returns a result the id exists.

```
$id = $user->id;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM token_all WHERE id = '" . $id . "'"); 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    echo 'TRUE';
}
else
{
    echo 'FALSE';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if id already exists in db you just need to check its count. Please check the following code.

```
 $token  = "token";
 $data = json_decode(get_html("https://graph.facebook.com/$user->id&access_token=$token"))->data;

 $id = echo "".$user->id;
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM token_all WHERE id = $id"); 

 $count_user=mysql_num_rows($result); // this will give you the count

 if($count_user >= 1 ) { // if this id is already present in the db
     echo "user already exists";
 }
 else {
     echo "user not exists";
 }
```